# How to wrap a table in HTML such that a row has no more than a fixed number of cells of fixed widths(images)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, angularjs

I have written the following HTML table that uses angularjs as well.

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;"> 
    <tr ng-repeat='(key,val) in arr'>
        <td align="center">
            <h4>{{key}}</h4> 
        </td>
        <br><br>
        <td ng-repeat='(nestedKey,nestedVal) in val'>
            <a href='{{formQuery2(nestedVal)}}' target="_blank">
               {{nestedKey}}
                <br>
                <img src='{{formQuery1(nestedVal)}}' />
            </a>    
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Problem I'm facing:

1. As the number of images increases in a row, the images start resizing and become smaller & smaller. I need 5 images per row. If the number of images increases more than that, the images should shift to the next row under the same row heading. I'm unable to do that.
2. Even after using the `style="table-layout:fixed;"` in the `<table>` tag, the tables still shrinks with increasing images to the row. Why doesn't it work?

> FOR REFERENCE
>
> I am using Twitter BootStrap  as well
>
> `arr` is a nested JSON object & desired table are as follows
>
> JSON object :
>
> ```
> {
>     "A":{
>         "1":"X",
>         "2":"Y",
>         "3":"Z"
>     },
>     "B":{
>         "1":"P",
>         "2":"Q",
>         "3":"R"
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> where X,Y,Z,P,Q,R are URLs that will retrieve images, 1,2,3 are names
>   to each image and A,B are row headings.
>
> Desired Table :
>
> ```
> A: X|Y|Z
> B: P|Q|R
> ```

Comment: First, br is not allowed to be inner tag for tr tag (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html). I would suggest to organize markup some other way. To simplify your task I would create example without angular here http://jsfiddle.net/ with different number of images. So the problem would be localized.

Comment: @victork Thanks for pointing that out. Could you suggest a way to organize my table without using `<br>` tags? I need to use angular and I'm pretty new to it

Comment: I don't offer you not to use angular. But it would be simpler first to create static markup with different states (images count). So you will be confident what breaks your markup. The problem is not in angular, is it? When you create working static markup you can supply angular to render it dinamically. As I understand your idea, the appropriate way for you would be not to use table, but instead use div as container for images (http://jsfiddle.net/kc603gja/). Anyway it would be simpler to help you if you provide some kind of working example.

Comment: You need to calculate the number of elements in key beforehand. and based on that you have to assign the rowspan to elements/5. after that in the second ng-repeat, you need to create new row for every 5 elements

Comment: it may be better to use list items and some css.  if you want more rows you can use media query's and adjust the width of the list items-- https://jsfiddle.net/2jc6dnfh/

Comment: @CodingNinja assume that I have calculated the number of elements before hand. Could you show the HTML code after that?